# How to create a SPA with Angular and MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have some back end services that I can easily surface using WebAPI and I want to call this resultant WebAPI layer from my front end.  I want to build a SPA using ASP.NET MVC 5, .cshtml files and AngularJS.  My question is how do I do this?  I know that I can use AJAX to call the WebApi layer in my Angular factories and services, this is not my issue.  My issue is how do I get MVC working with Angular so that I have a single page application?  Will the MVC routing interfere with Angular's routing?

Comment: MVC routing will not interfere with angular routing because angular routing will happen on client and mvc routing happen on server side so you could just create .html extension and put them in app/partials folder and server the html files without mvc intervention

Comment: How do I load .cshtml files though?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/), this on in particular [AngularJS for .NET Developers](http://pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-dotnet-developers)